# What should be in </distributionManagement> url

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to run a java (mvn) project by Jenkins job using the pipeline.

the cloning and the verify success but the deploy doesnt.

this is the error i got:

```
[main] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project create_pass_criteria: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

i am trining to fix it by adding this code to my pom.xml

```xml
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>corp1</id>
            <name>Corporate Repository</name>
            <url>file:///home/myfolder/.m2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

but how can i find the url that i should use ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The URL is the URL of the repository you want to deploy to.

Comment: The URL should be the one of your corporate repository in which you wish to deploy, or another external repository in which you have rights to publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have two different entries in distributionManagement. One for releases and one for snapshots. This the url of your internal repository manager:

```xml
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <name>release repo</name>
      <id>releases</id>
      <url>https://repomanager.com/base/maven-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <name>snapshots repo</name>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <url>https://repomanager.com/base/maven-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

The `<id>..</id>` references the entries in `settings.xml` file for authentication. The credentials should be configured in credentials store of Jenkins... (config file provider plugin in Jenkins is very helpful in such cases)

Comment: this link should be to my comuter? https://repomanager.com/base/maven-snapshots

Comment: Yes exactly. You have to adapt for your environment...

Comment: so can it be like this:             <url>C:\\work\myfolder</url>

Comment: or             <url>scp:\\C:\\work\myfolder</url>

Comment: I strongly recommend not to use scp etc. use http(s) instead and use a repository manager...

Comment: Your company should run a Nexus or Artifactory server that keeps all the build artifacts (and proxies the outside world).